# React reload component on dynamic route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
<Route path="/user/:username/" component={UserProfile} />
```

I have a route set up like above and having issue on

```
<Link to={"/user/" + userName + "/"}>user profile</Link>
```

When user goes to `/user/user1/` to `/user/user2/` because it does not reload the component but just update the states.

What is the best way to solve this issue? I need HTTP request in `componentDidMount` to be executes when username changes.

Comment: You probably need another lifecycle method than `componentDidMount`. `shouldComponentUpdate` will be called when your component's state is about to be changed, which reading from the last sentence is what you'll want to execute your HTTP request in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routed component doesn't reload when route parameters change. But it will call `componentWillReceiveProps()` as the component get different props. So call HTTP request inside both `componentWillReceiveProps()` and `componentDidMount` as React doesn't call `componentWillReceiveProps()` with initial props during mounting.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! This seems to be working but I have an another issue that's blocking for me to test this. in `compoeneWillReceiveProps()` I'm using `this.props.params.username` to make the HTTP request but it's showing the previous value instead of the new value that I can make an HTTP request. Any idea why?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) get the new props as an argument, so use `nextProps.params.username` instead of  `this.props.params.username` Read more here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Thank you so much exactly what I needed!

Comment: `ComponentWillRecieveProps` is unsafe and deprecated now. What to do now?